# Oracle SQL iterations

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume i have a SQL query in Oracle.

I have a table 'table_1' with a column named Status, it has 1 row that can have the values 'Done' or 'NotDone'.

The values in the Status column are updated automatically, depending on which time i look at it.

What i would like is a query that checks table_1 lets say every 5 minutes, until the column Status has gotten the value 'Done', then i would like that as an output.

If the Status column still has the value 'Notdone' i want to continue iterating until it has the value 'Done'

Best regards

Assume i have a SQL query in Oracle.

I have a table 'table_1' with a column named Status, it has 1 row that can have the values 'Done' or 'NotDone'.

Comment: It would be better to control this from the application side: open a new connection (or get it from pool), check the status and close it (or release to the pool) instead of a single long-running session that does nothing. Or use some callback functionality depending on your design.

Comment: Polling works best by scheduling, not by infinite loops + sleeping. What happens if your session is killed? Your whole regime breaks. Wherever your ETL tool runs from, use scheduling from that starting point to reach in and do the polling. If your ETL tool is in PL/SQL, using dbms_scheduler works well. if it's external to the database, it's not easy to have the database trigger something outside of it, so dbms_scheduler would not be the right choice. If your ETL tool is initiated from Unix, use cron. Etc..

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
DECLARE
  Status VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
  SELECT Status INTO Status FROM table_1;

  LOOP
    EXIT WHEN Status = 'Done';
  
    DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(5); -- 5 seconds
  
    SELECT Status INTO Status FROM table_1;
  END LOOP;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('FinalStatus: ' || Status);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you want that output? That is the main problem.
Mainly, when I have to check for something periodically, I do like this:

```
declare
  v_n number
begin
  loop
    select count(*) into v_n
    where status='DONE' and ... --- other conditions
      and rownum<=1; --- to avoid scanning the whole table for more rows once one is found
    if v_n>=1 then
      exit;
    end if;
    dbms_lock.sleep(180); --- seconds to wait
  end loop;
  --- do whatever needs to be done when the condition is satisfied 
  ...
end;
```

I do not really understand how you would like that as an output. I don't think it would be a good idea to include that in a function f_check_done and then select f_check_done from dual and have the  user wait indefinitely. Maybe to call a procedure to send a mail. Or use dbms_alert to raise an alert in the database. All depends on what you actually need

Comment: Hello, i want to use this query in an ETL tool  from my oracle query as a trigger.
So when the output from my query has 'Done' i want to trigger another job(Node) in my ETL.
A trigger check for me could be:
If the query has an output (i can use a trigger) would be an easy check.

Comment: In that case, to trigger something, better use dbms_scheduler.create_job, and submit a job that does  what needs to be done.

Comment: You could make that a `while` loop for extra style points. However I agree the whole query/trigger/ETL job approach is a bit puzzling and I'm not sure what *"use this query in an ETL tool from my oracle query as a trigger"* means exactly.